# iOS/XCode Framework to Simplify Remote Content Loading

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, afnetworking

So, this is a broader Question, since I realized a lot of us keep doing the same thing over and over.

- Display Data/Content as TableViews or Detailviews
- download this data dynamically from some Server ( a lot of Rails-Servers, maybe Django)

What I envision: Abstract the whole GET/POST/caching of those Objects and even the dynamic view-creation for arbitrary data-objects

So the only things the App has to do:

1. Hand a list of possible web services/Api-Calls inside some plist/dictionary, identified by "EntityName"
2. At Runtime, request or upload Entities by their Name and the Framework handles the whole Fetching/BackgroundAction/Posting/ Url-parsing
3. The app can even use customly generated views with outlets/labels according to the Data-Propertys

So, I was thinking about creating this on my own, using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) for the lower-level stuff. Before that, I just wanted to make sure, there's nothing out there that is doing this already.

(Something like a mirrored RubyOnRails-Framework for iPhone, that keeps DRY and ConventionOverConfiguration in mind the speed up development of CMS-managed iOS-Apps)

EDIT: In short words: Like a CRUD-Controller for a remote Database, that can be skinned/restricted to fit the customers/application needs.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know [Parse](https://parse.com)?

Maybe not exactly what your asking for, but definitely worth a try. They completely take away a lot of the server-side hassle.

Comment: Well in my case I have a bunch of really good RoR-Guys, so I wanted to streamline the Development on the Mobile-Device-side. So when they add new content the App's behaviour changes along the data-objects on the server, without frequent need of rebuilding your app.

Comment: Then I guess AFNetworking is a way to go. It's also not to hard to wright a handler on yout own (w/o AFNetworking).

Comment: Sure, I use AFNetworking in a number of projects. The plan is for a more highlevel approach, encapsulating arbitrary Database-Objects and showing arbitrary Data-base objects with a content-generated UI.